# Jquery Validate enable popup if form validates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/ on a form. I am also using a bit of javascript which means that the response of the form is opened in a popup window. The problem that I have is that if the form doesn't validate but the user tries to submit it then a blank popup window appears. I want the popup to appear only if the form validates. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<form id="contactform" action="formmail.php" method="post" name="contactform" onsubmit="popupform(this, 'join')">
    <input name="env_report" type="hidden" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT,AUTH_TYPE,REMOTE_USER" />
    <input name="recipients" type="hidden" value="me@mydomain.co.uk" />
    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/thankyou.html" name="good_url" />
    <input type="hidden" value="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/error.html" name="bad_url" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." name="realname" class="input-text required" required />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." name="email" class="input-text required" required />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone..." name="phone" class="input-text required" required />
    <input class="submit button" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").validate();
});

function popupform(contactform, windowname){
    if (! window.focus)return true;
    window.open('', windowname, 'height=250,width=500,scrollbars=no');
    contactform.target=windowname;
    return true;}
```

If you can help in anyway I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be going fine here, only a pop-up is shown when the fields are validated. However, be aware that the input type 'email' isn't checking for the actual format, all it checks for is that it contains an @. So asdf@a would considered to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling popupform using the onsubmit attribute of the form, call it from the submit handler of the validation plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactform").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            popupform(form, 'join');

            // do other things for a valid form
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```